# Parse open source server with mLab slow

Tags: ios, parse-server

I switched over to the open source parse with mLab on AWS and the project in objective c runs slow. When I try to update delete add or query it takes about five seconds to process it. I was not having this problem with the parse.com. If any one could help me that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

You are likely on a trial version of the server, which means that after 30 minutes of inactivity, your server will go to "sleep". When it is called to by a request, it must "wake up" which usually takes about 5 seconds. However, only the first query or log in after sleeping should actually be slow. The ones following should be very responsive.

Comment: @Ibdakine sure thing!